# Fastest way to update a MySQL table if row exists else insert. More than 2 non-unique keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have the following table structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reports` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `siteid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `visits` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )
```

Currently i check & insert/update with the following snippet:

```
 $checkq = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as rowexist FROM reports WHERE day='$day' AND uid='$uid' AND siteid='$sid' AND cid='$cid'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$checkr = mysql_fetch_array($checkq);

if ($checkr['rowexist'] > 0) {
 mysql_query("UPDATE reports_adv SET visits=visits+1 WHERE  day='$day' AND uid='$uid' AND siteid='$sid' AND cid='$cid'"); 
} else {
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO reports_adv SET day='$day', uid='$uid', siteid='$sid', cid='$cid', visits='1'");
}
```

Is a fastest way to update this MySQL table if row exists else insert with more than 2 non-unique keys?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

just use `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO reports_adv (day, uid, siteid, cid, visits) 
VALUES ('$day', '$uid', '$sid', '$cid', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE visits=visits+1;
```

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

but before anything else, you should define a `UNIQUE` constraint on the columns.

```
ALTER TABLE reports_adv  ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (day, uid, siteid, cid)
```

Comment: One more question. When i display the data i use on WHERE day, uid, siteid and cid. What indexes should i add?

Comment: None since this statement `UNIQUE (day, uid, siteid, cid)` implicitly adds an index for you.