# INSERT or UPDATE MySQL when updating non key indexed column?

Tags: mysql, insert, insert-update

I have a table that has an auto incremented id PK, and, among others columns, a column that has a non-unique index on it, but there is data in it I know IS unique, named column4.

Is it possible to do an

```
(INSERT if column4="this_data") or (UPDATE if column4!="this_data")
```

?

Or am I best just to use two queries - a SELECT to get the PK id of the row where column4="this_data", and then either an INSERT or UPDATE once I know whether the row exists?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html check this link

Comment: Why not just add the unique key?

Comment: The column holds user ids only if the user is of a particular type - for all other users I have zeros in there, which means I can't have a unique index. So, an example of data in that column from 5 rows might be 0,0,343555,0,0. Actually, should I replace the zeros with NULL? Can you have multiple nulls in a unique indexed column?

Comment: Thanks guys. I set the default of column4 to NULL, so now it will accept a UNIQUE index, which allows the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

```
INSERT INTO table (col) 
VALUES ('$val')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col=col+1;
```

Or you can try  :-

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```

[More details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Thanks Rahautos. That isn't working, as they can have multiple rows the way the indexes are set up, so the ON DUPLICATE KEY doesn't get triggered.

Comment: This relies on the column having a unique key, which the OP explicitly stated that it doesn't

Comment: for more details please check this :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797510/fastest-way-to-update-a-mysql-table-if-row-exists-else-insert-more-than-2-non-u

Comment: Both of your references support my point.. from the dev docs: 'If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed.' Now that the OP has added the UNIQUE key it will, so I will remove the down vote if you add this to the answer.