# Update record if "title" already exists in table when inserting

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo

I have `tag` table in my MySql db like this.

```
Id    Title    RepeatCount
--------------------------
 1     Tag1        1
 2     Tag2        5
 3     Tag3        8
```

I want to insert record into table in PDO, If record with same `Title` not exist (`Title` is primary key) and if exist, Increase record `RepeatCount`.

Like this example:

```
prepare(
    "IF (:Title IN (SELECT Title FROM tag)) 
     THEN INSERT INTO tag (Title) VALUES (:Title)
     ELSE UPDATE tag SET RepeatCount = RepeatCount + 1"
);
execute(array(
    ":Title" => "MyTag"
));
```

Comment: Why not use `INSERT  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390093/how-can-i-use-on-duplicate-key-update-in-pdo-with-mysql

Comment: just reorder to : 1. `update .. where title = ..` 2. `insert into .. where not in ..`

Comment: That is what do you search for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797510/fastest-way-to-update-a-mysql-table-if-row-exists-else-insert-more-than-2-non-u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL SQL, control flow statements such as `if` are only valid in stored blocks, such as stored procedures, functions, and triggers.  A better way to do this process is to use `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into tag(Title)
    values (:Title)
    on duplciate key update RepeatCount = RepeatCount + 1;
```

This is better because the database handles race conditions, so you don't have to worry about values being overwritten.  Note:  this assumes that `RepeatCount` is initialized to a number and not to `NULL`.